# How to Subquery to pull rows from a table based on MAX(DateTime and another value within the same table?

Tags: sql, subquery

First, I'm admittedly new to SQL and want to thank you in advance for any assistance.

I basically need to create a subquery to identify a list of Intake.id  who are currently listed as 'Active' within the DefendantStatusHistory tbl. Subqueries always get the best of me and I'm completely lost.

Because a Client will at times be 'Inactive' as a result of numerous reasons, my users change the status of a client by adding a new record in the DefendantStatusHistory tbl. Each time they add a record, a datetime record is created in the defendantstatushistory tbl, TimeStampCreated column.  I need to pull the max datetime of the, TimeStampCreated column where the value of the Status column is = 'Active'.

- As i said, I'm new to SQL and subqueries have me stumped. What I've tried, see below pulls all clients who ever had an 'Active' record in the DefendantStatusHistory tbl.

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(d.FirstName,' ',d.MiddleName,' ',d.LastName) AS [Client Name],
    i.County, 
    i.SupervisingOfficer,
    i.SupervisionLevel AS [Supervision Level],
    ds.Status
FROM Defendants d 
JOIN Intake i ON d.ID = i.DefendantID
JOIN DefendantStatusHistory ds on ds.IntakeID = i.ID
        WHERE ds.Status = 'Active'
```

I need help with creating a subquery of the DefendantStatusHistory tbl, for the max datetime of the TimeStampCreated column, where the Status column is = 'Active' and then put is all together.

Again, thank you in advance for your assistance!

Haus

Answer (score 0):

you can try a subquery as part of a `join`

```
    SELECT CONCAT (
        d.FirstName
        ,' '
        ,d.MiddleName
        ,' '
        ,d.LastName
        ) AS [Client Name]
    ,i.County
    ,i.SupervisingOfficer
    ,i.SupervisionLevel AS [Supervision Level]
FROM Defendants d
JOIN Intake i ON d.ID = i.DefendantID
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
         intakeid
        ,STATUS
        ,max(TimeStampCreated) OVER (
            PARTITION BY intakeid ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) AS recent
    FROM defendantstatushistory
    WHERE STATUS = 'Active'
    GROUP BY intakeid
        ,STATUS
        ,defendantstatushistory.TimestampCreated
    ) ds ON ds.intakeid = i.id
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much further than my limited experience has gotten me. When I attempt to use your code, I get, "Invalid column name  'recent'". Any thoughts on resolving this? Thanks again for your help? -Haus

Comment: sorry, not able to help much without seeing further data.  i named the aggregate max column 'recent' as an alias, you can try it without `group by recent`

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to help. I edited the SQL, removed the 'recent' from the GROUP BY and added TimestampCreated to the GROUP BY. This now provides a list of clients and is much closer. The SQL is creating duplicates? Because a client will come in and out of 'Active' status, there is sometime multiple records that indicate 'Active'. I think that the SQL Code is going to the DefendantStatusHistory tbl, and finding multiple max(TimeStampCreated) where the Status = 'Active'. If you have any thoughts on resolving this, it would be much appreciated. Thank you, Haus

Comment: is the data (`intakeid` and `TimestampCreated`) exactly the same for the duplicates?  in that case you can have `select distinct` instead of just `select` in the subquery.  if not, i'm not sure because it should be segmenting the data by `intakeid`

Comment: This did the trick. Thank you so much for following back up with this. I edited the SQL you provided to reflect the changes I ultimately made. Thanks again! -Haus